# Repeatedly popping "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')" after routing a particular screen

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation, onpress, navigateurl

```js
const ResolvedPlaces = ({navigation}) => {
return(
 <View style={Styles.headerWrapper}>
                <TouchableOpacity navigation={navigation} onPress={()=> navigation.navigate("ProfileScreen")} >
                <Text style={[Styles.header,{fontWeight:"bold"}]}>Resolved </Text> 
                <Text style={Styles.header}> places</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
)

}
```

I have created a ResolvedPlaces function and gave a option to route to the profile screen. Also I've destructured the "navigation" in all format. But I continuously got this navgation.navigate as undefined object.
[the error message on the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uP936.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `ResolvedPlaces` is not defined as a `Screen` in a `react-native-navigation navigator`, then the `navigation prop` will not be passed automatically to the  component `ResolvedPlaces`.

If `ResolvedPlaces` is nested inside a `Screen` that is defined in a `Navigator`, then you can use the `navigation prop` directly. This could look as follows.

```js
const SomeScreen = ({navigation}) => {

    const ResolvedPlaces = () => {
        return(
             <View style={Styles.headerWrapper}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> navigation.navigate("ProfileScreen")} >
                <Text style={[Styles.header,{fontWeight:"bold"}]}>Resolved </Text> 
                <Text style={Styles.header}> places</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          )
       }
  
  return (
      <ResolvedPlaces />
  )
}
```

The component `SomeScreen` must be defined in a navigator, e.g. a `Stack`.

If `ResolvedPlaces` is a component defined in its own file, then pass the `navigation` object as a prop from the parent that is defined as a screen.

```js
const SomeScreen = ({navigation}) => {
    return <ResolvedPlaces navigation={navigation} />
}
```

If this is not an option than you can still use the `useNavigation` hook as follows.

```js
const ResolvedPlaces = () => {

    const navigation = useNavigation()

    return (
        <View style={Styles.headerWrapper}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> navigation.navigate("ProfileScreen")} >
                <Text style={[Styles.header,{fontWeight:"bold"}]}>Resolved </Text> 
                <Text style={Styles.header}> places</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
    )
}
```

**Remarks:** I have removed the navigation prop from the `TouchableOpacity` since this prop does not exist for this component. The basic `react-native-navigation` structure is documented [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation).

Comment: I couldn't rectify the complexed components navigation. Later I tried in your useNavigation hook method. Now it is working. Thank you